# How to change a part of Sentence after specific string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this Sentence `" Hi ~r~ I'm the ~b~ BOSS "`

I want to change string after `"~r~"` by putting it in a span with red color,
and string after `" ~b~ "` by putting it in a span with black color.
***This example has just 2 colors but I may want to have many more colors with other codes***
I want the output string to look something like the following:

```
"Hi" + "<span style='color: red;'>i'm the</span>" + "<span style='color: black;'>BOSS</span>"
```

Comment: Have you tried string.replace()? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @Sylvain but how I can get string after ~r~ without getting string contain ~b~ BOSS

Comment: Have you tried to put all your markers ~r~ and their corresponding replacements in an array, loop and search if a string in your array is present in your sentence and replace it if it is found?

Comment: @Sylvain the replacement is easily I think but how to get string after ~r~ without getting string after ~b~ or another statement

Comment: @EXP where the ~r~ ends

Comment: @User863 the ends is " I'm the ", stop before another statement ~b~ or any other statement ~y ~, ~g~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/DnPoqR/1)

```js
let text = " Hi ~r~ I'm the ~b~ BOSS "
let colors = { r: 'red', b: 'blue' }

document.body.innerHTML = text.replace(/~([a-z])~(.*?)(?=~|$)/g, (match, p1, p2) => {
  return `<span style="color:${colors[p1]}">${p2}</span>`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dynamically change that you can use regex search and replace, but the easier way would be just using javascript [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), u can do this:

```
let sentence  = "Hi ~r~ I'm the ~b~ BOSS"
sentence = sentence.replace("~r~ I'm the", "<span style='color: red;'>I'm the</span>")
sentence = sentence.replace("~b~ BOSS", "<span style='color: black;'>BOSS</span>")
console.log(sentence)
// Hi <span style='color: red;'>I'm the</span> <span style='color: black;'>BOSS</span>
```

Comment: This example is not static, it can be change

Answer (score 0):

I think, it can help you. But you need to improve it.

```js
var str = "Hi ~r~ I'm the ~b~ BOSS";
var red = str.indexOf("~r~") + 2;
var black = str.indexOf("~b~") + 2;
var t = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == " ") {
        t += c;
    } else if (i>red && i<black-2) {
        t += "<span>" + c + "</span>";
    } else {
        t+= c;
    }
}
var tilde = '~';
var t = t.replace(new RegExp(`${tilde}(.*?)${tilde}`,'gm'), '')
document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = t;
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="view"></div>
```

Comment: for other colours how it can be running like blue, pink, etc 
and how I can remove the statement of colour ~r~ in the result ?

Comment: You can use class id for each colors if you know CSS and to remove element you can use Regular Expression.

Comment: the method to change colour its many, but how I can select the string after any statement like ~g~ and stop before another statement after that I can replace with span and use if statement to see if ~g~ will be green ~y~ will be yellow

Comment: I added regular expression.

Comment: @EXP I think best solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669977/6074164

Answer (score 0):

I have here one of the best performing way to carry out the task. It is of order O(n):

## Solution WITHOUT Regex:

```js
function addColors(ele) {
  let str = ele;
  let hasSpan = false;
  let ansStr = "";
  for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] === '~') {
      i++;
      switch(str[i]) {
        case 'r':
          if(hasSpan) {
            ansStr = str.slice(0, i-1) + "<span><span style='color: red;'>" + str.slice(i+2);
          } else {
            ansStr = str.slice(0, i-1) + "<span style='color: red;'>" + str.slice(i+2);
            hasSpan = true;
          }
          str = ansStr;
          i = i+2;
          break;
        case 'b':
          if(hasSpan) {
            ansStr = str.slice(0, i-1) + "<span><span style='color: black;'>" + str.slice(i+2);
          } else {
            ansStr = str.slice(0, i-1) + "<span style='color: black;'>" + str.slice(i+2);
            hasSpan = true;
          }
          str = ansStr;
          i = i+2;
          break;
        default:
          console.log(i, str[i+1], "DEFAULT")
      }
    }
  }
  if(hasSpan) {
    str = str + "</span>"
  }
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<h1>WATCH THIS!</h1>
<input type="text" name="jhtml" value="Hi ~r~ I'm the ~b~ BOSS">
<button onclick="addColors(document.getElementsByName('jhtml')[0].value)">Add Colors</button>
```

## Solution using Regex:

```js
function addColors(ele) {
  let colors = { r: 'red', b: 'blue' }
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = ele.replace(/~([a-z])~(.*?)(?=~|$)/g, (match, p1, p2) => {
  return `<span style="color:${colors[p1]}">${p2}</span>`
})
}
```

```html
<h1>WATCH THIS!</h1>
<input type="text" name="jhtml" value="Hi ~r~ I'm the ~b~ BOSS">
<button onclick="addColors(document.getElementsByName('jhtml')[0].value)">Add Colors</button>
```